# ImportError: cannot import name _counter

Tags: python, python-2.x, windows-10

Я создаю приложение по шифрованию сообщений на Python 2.7 с использованием библиотеки pyCrypto. В ходе исполнения кода:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

from AESEncDec import *
from MD5Hashing import *
from RSAEncDec import *

color = 'lightblue' #color our background


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.frame_width = 700
        self.frame_height = 400
    ....
#create object TK class
the_window = Tk(className = " Cryptographic")
#create object Application
app = Application(the_window)
#run our Application
app.mainloop()
```

Выдается следующая ошибка:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _counter
```

Эта проблема только на Windows 10, на Линуксе подобной ошибки нет, все работает. Я добавлял `from Crypto.Util import _counter`, но это не помогло. В чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: Что-то у вас в коде нет строки с импортом данного модуля. Возможно косяк в одной из библиотек которую вы используете

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Возможно, какая-то библиотека криво установилась и стоит попробовать переустановить

Comment: @insolor Ya v etom plane neopyten, kak eto sdelatj?

Comment: @ArturoGonzalez текст ошибки обычно состоит не из одной строки. Там должен быть полный стек вызовов, и там должно быть видно в каком модуле выскакивает ошибка

Comment: @insolor компилятор останавливается на этой строке и выдает только эту ошибку

Comment: @ArturoGonzalez, на какой "этой"? У вас нет строки, где импортируется имя `_counter`

Comment: не используйте: `from module import *` форму, особенно в вопросах, касающихся ошибок с импортом. Уберите из кода всё не нужное (если ошибка осталась, когда вы убрали код, то он не нужный для вопроса) -- больше одной строки здесь не нужно. Приведите полное сообщение об ошибке буквально как его python печатает. Укажите явно установленные версии пакета, которые к ошибке ведут. Если не знаете как какой-то шаг сделать, спрашивайте ("как установить X модуль для Python 2.7 на Windows" лучше как отдельный вопрос задать).